# What is the maximum and minimum of 'q' value in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

When extract a image from a Video via ffmpeg, can get message like below.

```
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=2.5 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A
```

and that 'q' value means "quality of coded frames". 
I found this by searching code ffmpeg.c.(reference Link : http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/frame_8h_source.html#l00205)

And normally it has value between 0.0 to 6.0. 
But the problem is it can get much higher value by reference.
The code says,

```
 fprintf(vstats_file, "frame= %5d q= %2.1f ", frame_number, enc->coded_frame->quality / (float)FF_QP2LAMBDA);
```

and the range of quality value is 1 to 32,767. and FF_QP2LAMBDA is 118.
So we can get maximum value of %2.1f is over 277. And it is very suspicious (because of "%2.1f").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without going too much in the details of video encoding, you can look at both Quantization Parameters (QP) or the Lambda parameter to express the quality of an encoded frame.

[image]

This figure was taken from [*Xiaoyin, Cheng – Subjectively Optimized HDTV Video Coding, 2009*](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/95351.pdf). You can think of Lambda as a the Lagrangian multiplier in the [Rate-Distortion Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate%E2%80%93distortion_optimization) process.

If you take a macroblock and encode it with a low QP, the distortion (*D*) in comparison to the original image will be low, but the bit rate (*R*) will be high. Likewise, if you choose a high QP, the distortion will be high, but the bit rate will be low. So, the cost of compressing a frame is calculated by *J = D + λR* – and this cost needs to be minimized.

In your specific case, I'm fairly certain that `enc->coded_frame->quality` is assigned Lambda values from the encoder. With the `FF_QP2LAMBDA` constant you can convert to Lambda units, e.g. let *QP = 21*, then *λ = 21 × `FF_QP2LAMBDA`*. The other way round, you get the QP by *QP = λ / `FF_QP2LAMBDA`*, which is what you're seeing in the output.

For example, in H.264, the basic relation is *λ = 0.85 × 2<sup>(QP-12)/3</sup>*. Since QP values range from 0 to 51, you get Lambda values between 0.053 and 6,963.2 – but FFmpeg will output the QP values anyway, by converting Lambda back into QP.

Now, when you say "range of quality value is 1 to 32,767", you mean the range of possible Lambda values. Since the Lagrangian function only comes into play *after* the QP is applied to the coded macroblock, there is a practical limit to the maximum number that `coded_picture->quality` can get. For example, in MPEG-4 Part 2, QP values go from 1–31, and like I said above, in MPEG-4 Part 10, it's from 0–51. In return, the `q=` will output the correct QP again, because the possible Lambda values are limited by what QP you chose before.

Comment: Thanks for such an explanation. Are you one of ffmpeg contributor?:D I have an additional question, if you do not mind. Now I understand basic concept of QP(Quantization Parameter), Lambda, D(Distortion), But what about 'J'? Thanks again.

Comment: I'm not really a contributor in code, just a contributor of documentation and user support, if you will :) *J* is just the cost of the Lagrangian function which you want to minimize. This is, in essence, basic optimization mathematics. It is explained in the paper I linked you to in Section 1.5.3, but you will find generalizations about this in almost any good mathematics text book.